# Using WebKit for local (no internet access) data gathering?

Tags: android, ios, webkit

My CTO has this idea that if we use WebKit on our new mobile app, that we can render locally stored XML to the screen and then get user input to be saved locally in a database or file. (no access to servers)

Has anyone seen WebKit used in this fashion?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean has anyone ever displayed a local webpage?  Of course...it's no different than showing a remote one.

Comment: PhoneGap, titanium namen them they all use this technique. But it slow does not feel native enough, but does work.

Comment: I know it can be used to display a page, but can I get the user data without sending a form back to a server? Also, can I specify user input fields with XML or does it need to be HTML?